# Can I save iOS App Crash Report to Document Directory?

Tags: ios

Can I save iOS App Crash Report to Document Directory?

My application get crashing again and again on application launch. I want to save my application crash log to document directory. Please help!

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get access to the crash reports that iOS creates from inside your app as those reports are located outside of the apps sandbox environment.

The only way to get access to crash reports from within your apps process, you'd need to integrate a 3rd party crash reporting framework.

Comment: How do that frameworks work? I mean they are part of an app and should not have access to the crash reports too.